# How can I execute a Javascript function from VBScript?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, vbscript, wsh

I'm trying to download an Excel file from a webpage by using WSH scripts

My objective is to save the Excel file from a webpage onto my machine.

So far, the steps I've taken are: Made a vbs file, which logs into the https webpage, redirects me to another page using the second run command that opens up a new tab but after that my limited knowledge isn't able to find a solution as to how to download the file from the download link on the website to a location on my hard drive.

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "URL", 9
wscript.sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "username@"
WshShell.SendKeys "{tab}"
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WshShell.Run "Another_URL"
```

Now at this point there is a Download Link which has a javascript function `javascript:download(parameters)` which upon manual click generates a unique download link.

Is there any way I can download this using any Wscript? I want it to work with Windows 7 and IE 7. I have tried looking into it but it is of no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some success using a script similar to this

```
option explicit

Const URL = "http://url/to/file.xls"
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

' request the file over http
dim http: set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.open "GET", URL, false
http.send

' write the response text to a binary file
dim stream: set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.type = adTypeBinary 
stream.open
stream.write http.responseBody
stream.SaveToFile "output.xls", adSaveCreateOverWrite 
stream.close
```

although I haven't used it for https requests, I'm assuming that the server will accept your username and password as the 4th and 5th parameters to the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`'s `open` call.

```
http.open "GET", URL, false, "username@", "password"
```

I've tried it and it certainly works over a plain http request

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(VS.85).aspx for http request and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032(VS.85).aspx for adodb stream

---

Well an alternative to the above could be to use the Internet Explorer automation object. I'm not sure how you could handle a file download, but the following snippet might give you a starting point

```
option explicit

' create an instance of IE
dim ie: set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
' load a url
ie.Navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677595/how-can-i-execute-a-javascript-function-from-vbscript"
' sleep while IE loads the content
do while ie.busy
    WScript.Sleep 10
loop
'access the document object
dim doc: set doc = ie.document

' have IE natvigate to a link on the downloaded page. this could be your
' download link perhaps?
ie.Navigate doc.anchors(0).href 
' wait while the new page loads...
do while ie.busy
    WScript.Sleep 10
loop
' output the new content
WScript.Echo doc.documentElement.innerHTML
' close IE
ie.Quit
```

Comment: This is the link that is generated https://Fixed_URL/Random_No_Generated?_tbldnld=(1st param)&sc=(2nd param of fn) Manually this is what happens, after clicking download it opens a FIle download box, which then I click on save to save it onto a location. URL doesn't has the file name, but the name is same to that of the random no. So, can I mimick this behaviour progmatically, if yes is it possible using scripts or any program must be written - please guide me and if not why is it not possible.thank you oracle certified professior for helping but i see not how to solve this.